# Run loop while boolean == true

Tags: python

I literally can't find a solution for this small problem, i just want the loop to start if PASS = True.
When i run the programme it creates the directory but exits without an error.

```
if check_dir == False:
    #creates the directory
    os.mkdir(dir_path)
Createdfilescounter = 0
lenght_files = len(files) - 1
kamel = False
for file in files:
    if Createdfilescounter == lenght_files:
        kamel = True
    with open(dir_path + extend + file, "w") as f:
        f.write("File saved")
```

---

```
while kamel:
    def takess():
        im = ImageGrab.grab()
        im.save(dir_path+ "/" + "screenshot.png")
```

Comment: you don't increment your counter after creating the file

Comment: You a life saver man, sorry for my stupidity im just overwhelmed i've been working on this beginner project for 2 days and i love coding that i forgot to take care of myself i guess i got take a rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ti7, i forgot to increment my counter.